# Word order with "daher?"

Tags: word-order, conjunction, subordinate-clause

I wrote the sentence:

> Ich bin ein Vegetarier, daher ich esse kein Fleisch.

One person corrected it to:

> Ich bin ein Vegetarier, daher esse ich kein Fleisch.

Another person (not native German) told me that *daher* seems like it should be a subordinating conjunction so it should send the verb (*esse*) to the end.

When I wrote the original sentence I assumed it was like *aber*, the second person thinks it’s like *weil*, and the other correction is like neither. I read [this page](https://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Konjunktionen/Konjunktionen.html) but couldn’t find *daher.* Could someone please clear up the grammatical situation of this word for me?

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/daher). Please check a dictionary of your choice in situations like these ;) *Daher* is not a conjunction. Also welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take the [tour]. And consult the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: *Daher* ist ein *Konjunktionaladverb*. Ich empfehle diese Seite, wenngleich *daher* nicht vorkommt: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/konjunktionen?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0

Comment: Schouldn't it be "Ich bin Vegetarier"? ohne "ein"?

Comment: @Beta: short answer: both are correct. Post it as a question for the long answer ;-)

Comment: @Jan Was? Ich glaube es ist immer ein Adverb, aber ich bin kein Grammatikmeister, wie ich schon mehrfach schrieb!

Comment: @Jan ich meinte: ist ein Konjunktionsladverb. Zu deren Gebrauch siehe... Das ist doch in Ordnung, oder?

Comment: @Ludi Stimmt; ich hab das iwie auf meinen Kommentar bezogen. Entschuldigung!

Comment: Inhaltlich ist es eine Tautologie, weil Vegetarier zu sein nicht erklärt, wieso man kein Fleisch ist, sondern genau das bedeutet. "Ich esse kein Fleisch, daher bin ich Vegetarier" würde immerhin dazu taugen einem Kind das Fremdwort zu erklären. Ansonsten ist es so sinnfrei wie zu sagen "Ich bin dick, daher bin ich fett" oder umgekehrt.

Answer (score 9):

Daher is an *adverb,* that roughly means "therefore."

Thus, it occupies the first spot in the second sentence, and sends the verb to the second spot.

> "Ich bin ein Vegetarier; daher esse ich kein Fleisch" is correct.

Daher is *not* a subordinating conjunction that sends the verb to the end.

Nor is it a coordinating conjunction, which would allow you to keep te original word order, "daher ich esse kein Fleisch."